# Wrong Vesting Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, tokens, etherscan

For my project I created vesting contract. The contract codes and vesting contract codes are same with MATIC token contracts but in my vesting contract there is wrong. https://etherscan.io/address/0xcbfe11b78c2e6cb25c6eda2c6ff46cd4755c8fca#readContract . If you check this link there is owner and token. It is true but in my vesting contract both owner and token are same which is main wallet adress. I entered wrong thing for token. I wrote main adress for _token but it must be TOKEN contract adress. Now can we change this or upgrade this.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `retrieveExcessTokens` or `addVesting` functions to get the tokens out of the contract?

Comment: How can I withdraw tokens with addVesting? Token information is wrong

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get your tokens out. Please post the actual addresses and contract code so we can take a better look

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0xbf357f4ccc35ae6efdc77a8e9b74b6562ffe3116#code look at from reading. owner and token informations are same and look at original matic vesting contract token is different

Comment: There is no way to withdraw the tokens. I recommend re-deploying everything

Comment: Are you sure sir because ı can not deploy again. Can we use different function or something?

Answer (score 1):

As you have not made the contracts upgradable at deployment, you can't upgrade it. I would forget about this and deploy a new one. Hopefully you haven't deployed tokens to it.